# Can i dualboot UBUNTU 12.04 64 bit along with WINDOWS 7 32 bit?

Tags: installation

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 64bit along side with windows 7 32 bit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Dual-booting is a very easy process with almost no risk. Here's the safest way you can do it:

1. Start up your Ubuntu Live CD, changing your BIOS settings if necessary to boot a CD.
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu Before Installing." That way, you can see if everything works.
3. If everything does work, double-click "Install Ubuntu" on your desktop.
4. Go through the settings until you reach "How would you like to install Ubuntu?"
5. Choose "Install Alongside Windows 7" and accept the default configuration.
6. Finish going through the configuration, then wait for Ubuntu to install.

It is possible you will be unable to boot into Ubuntu. Here's how you can fix that:

1. Start up your Live CD again and choose "Try Ubuntu Before Installing."
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in to open Terminal.
3. Type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and let the command run.
5. Type `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Choose the "Recommended Repair"
7. Follow the instructions you are given.
8. Reboot when done.

It is also possible you will be unable to boot Windows. If that happens, do this:

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in to open Terminal.
3. Type `sudo update-grub` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Reboot when done.

By now, you should have Ubuntu and Windows 7 in a proper dual boot configuration. Good luck with your install!